# Remapping Egyptian Hieroglyphs

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex

> Please save your time and energy on this question, I also provide a potential solution.

**Notice:** There are much better fonts for hieroglyphs these days, this problem is quite old-fashioned. It's indeed a question for archaeologists!

In the old days, I was using WYSIWYG editors. After installing and selecting a font, we type letters and we get glyphs from the font, literally it could be anything: letters, symbols, chess pieces, glyphs, kanjis, or, hieroglyphs.

I have downloaded several TTF files from http://www.rockwellweb.com/hiero.htm and I was quite surprised it wasn't working in TeX as expected. Let's say we try to get several hieroglyphs from `GARDAE__.TTF`. How to get output similar to a screenshot below where I typed `abcdef`?

I also enclose a MWE for `xelatex` and `lualatex`. We are getting 12 rectangles in XeLaTeX and an empty page in LuaLaTeX.

[image: an example from wysiwyg editor]

```
% run: xelatex or lualatex mal-hiero-mwe.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\changeto{\setmainfont{GARDAE__.TTF}}
\def\hiero#1{{\changeto#1}}
\begin{document}
\hiero{abcdef}\par
\hiero{ABCDEF}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was so happy I've found this old problem of mine for the solvers that I tried an experiment or two and I've *accidentally* solved it. This is it, if you don't mind.

> **The problem**

The problem is that glyphs are mapped in public use areas, from `F000` to `F0FF` instead of a series from `0000` to `00FF`, WYSIWYG editors are handling that well. I've used OpenOffice Writer for this task.

> **Solution in XeLaTeX**

We can prepare mapping file on our own, I have done that on a small scale, but I needed to remap all 256 glyphs at once, if possible. I started to experiment with `UniClass`, an option I found in ITRANS's map files in the TeX Live distribution. Let this be our experimental mapping file `hiero-ae.map`:

```
; An experiment with UniClass...
LHSName "Keystrokes"
RHSName "GardinerAE"
LHSDescription "The keystrokes from the user"
RHSDescription "Output suitable for Gardiner AE.ttf"
pass(Unicode)
UniClass [keystrokes] = (U+0000 .. U+00FF)
UniClass [hieroglyphs] = (U+F000 .. U+F0FF)
[keystrokes] <> [hieroglyphs]
```

We only need to compile it with `teckit_compile`, e.g. by running:

```
teckit_compile hiero-ae.map -o hiero-ae.tec
```

Our last step is to load it in XeLaTeX. Worth mentioning is fact that mapping is not ready in LuaLaTeX to my best knowledge. I enclose an example and I will enclose a preview of the PDF file at the end of this post.

```
% run: xelatex mal-hieroglyphs.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\hiero#1{{\setmainfont[Mapping=hiero-ae]{GARDAE__.TTF}#1}}
\begin{document}
\hiero{abcdef}\par
\hiero{ABCDEF}
\end{document}
```

> **Solution in LuaLaTeX**

I've also tried to solve this task in LuaLaTeX. I am replacing character by character in Lua using `string.byte` and `string.format`. I enclose the TeX code and a preview of the result.

```
% run: lualatex mal-hiero-luatex.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\def\changeto{\setmainfont{GARDAE__.TTF}}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function processme(text)
--print(text) -- The processed part...
for char=1,#text do
  value="F0"..string.format("%02X",string.byte(text,char))
  --print(value) -- The value of a character...
  tex.sprint("\\char\""..value)
end -- of for char...
--tex.sprint(text)
end -- of function processme...
\end{luacode*}
\def\hiero#1{{\changeto\directlua{processme("#1")}}}
\begin{document}
\hiero{abcdef}\par
\hiero{ABCDEF}
\end{document}
```

[image: a preview of our efforts]

Comment: I tried to compile your code for LuaLaTeX using TeXShop.  After a long compilation I got the fontspec error: "font-not-found"  The font "GARDAE_.TTF" cannot be found.  I do not have the font; I know that.:)  Where can I find this font?

Comment: @Sony I downloaded the font from http://www.rockwellweb.com/hiero.htm.